# How to add Edit action in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to perform an edit action on my blog page. I have other action such as ADD, DELETE and GET.

Any suggestion to add EDIT action on the same and perform my blog editable on button click?

Any help would be helpful.

//Action.js

```
export const getBlog = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(setResumesLoading());
    axios
        .get('/api/blogs')
        .then(res => 
            dispatch({
                type: types.GET_BLOG,
                payload: res.data
            })
        ).catch (err => dispatch (returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
};

export const addBlog = blog => (dispatch, getState) => {
   axios
   .post('/api/blogs', blog, tokenConfig(getState))
   .then(res => 
    dispatch({
        type: types.ADD_BLOG,
        payload: res.data
    })).catch (err => dispatch (returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
};



export const deleteBlog = id => (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios
    .delete(`/api/blogs/${id}`, tokenConfig(getState)).then(res => 
        dispatch({
            type: types.DELETE_BLOG,
            payload: id

        })).catch (err => dispatch (returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
};
```

//Reducer.js

```
case types.GET_BLOG:
   return {
     ...state,
     blogs: action.payload,
     loading: false
   };
 case types.DELETE_BLOG:
   return {
    ...state,
    blogs: state.blogs.filter(blog => blog._id !== action.payload)
   };
 case types.ADD_BLOG:
   return {
     ...state,
     blogs: [action.payload, ...state.blogs]
   };
```

//Current UI
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const editBlog = (id, blog) => (dispatch, getState) => {
   axios
   .put(`/api/blogs/${id}`, blog, tokenConfig(getState))
   .then(res => 
    dispatch({
        type: types.EDIT_BLOG,
        payload: res.data
    })).catch (err => dispatch (returnErrors(err.response.data, 
     err.response.status)));
};
```

// Reducer

```
case types.EDIT_BLOG:
     return {
        ...state,
        updatedBlog: action.payload, // Or do what ever you want
        loading: false
};
```

Comment: Hi Viswanath, thanks for your time . Do we really need to add like 
`updatedBlog: action.payload,`  ? Or we can add like `blogs: action.payload,` ?

Comment: blogs is your list of blog.That you show as a list right ? If your update API is returning only the updated blog, then you should keep it in another variable. You can even call the GET api again to rerun the sort order after update.

Comment: Alright. So on click of edit and updating the data it will return the new data and it will update the current accordingly. Is it what you mean to say. If I am not wrong.

Comment: So how can I call the get API again here.

Comment: Once the reducer gets called. Your component will reload. From there you can trigger GET Api, or you can update the list with updated data if sort order is not an issue.

Comment: Any suggestion how can I pass te blog data into my edit modal with prefilled data and edit/save after that.

Comment: Just pass the data as props to modal component. Like

`<ModelComponent blog={blogData} />`

Inside that you can access the data like

`this.props.blog`

Comment: Please go though few blogs on usage of props etc. 

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212134/discussion-between-tanmoy-sarkar-and-viswanath-lekshmanan).

Comment: So I am passing it to my component like `<EditBlog key={_id}  blogs={activeBlogs} /> ` and want to display my data as per the `key=id`. Is it the correct way to do so?

Comment: Depends ? Is that what you want ? key is just a unique string to differentiate the instance of a component.

Comment: could you please give me some support on this code? so as per all blogs and tutorial suggest that if we pass the key then it will be easier to display the data of the particular blog.

Answer (score 0):

This can be maintained at the component level also, A boolean flag called ***editBlog*** -> true/false.

> Update the component state by toggling the *editBlog* flag on click of edit block button.

Comment: I want to add an action type as mentioned in title. which will call an API an other.